# Find Percentage of differences between two Images using Python "imgdiff" library

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am working with Image comparison using python "Imgdiff" library. I have images name "image1 and image2". I can find the difference between two images using following command,

> imgdiff "D:\Project Doc\image mining\Compare images\image1.jpg"
>   "D:\Project Doc\image mining\Compare images\image2.jpg" -H

It shows the result image with highlight the difference. But here I want to find how many percent (ie: 20%) image1 different from image2. How to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "percentage of differences"?

Comment: how many percentage second image change from first image.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Thank you  GoBrewers. There is any solution for this.??

Comment: Jai, I think there was some sarcasm in there... You didn't provide any precision whatsoever in your answer, and what you call "percentage of difference" still isn't clearly defined even when we know it's between 2 images. You'll have to explain more clearly what you want if you hope to get any help...

Comment: I edited my question. I think it explain my problem.

Comment: It explains your problem but it does not explains what you mean by "percentage of differences".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is simply not possible according to documentation: 
http://pythonhosted.org/imgdiff/

For example image magick can do that:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/209517/does-diff-exist-for-images

Comment: I use image magick for find the percentage of difference between image. Its working nice. thank you.:-)